# Relational querying in mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following models in my app and I am using mongoid

User, Account, Office and Leads
A user has many accounts and an account belongs to a user
An account has many offices and an office belongs to an account
An office has many leads and a lead belongs to an office

Now I want to query such that I want to get the leads belonging to the offices of accounts of a user, like `

```
@accounts = Account.where(:user => user)
```

Now I want to get the leads of the offices belonging to @accounts. Is there a decent way to accomplish it? or I have to iterate over each account and get the offices belonging to that account and then ultimately find the leads.

I could persist the account information in the leads itself so that they contain both the account and office information so that I can query in one shot. But is that the right way?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are "contains" relationships consider embedding rather than linking.  For example if all leads belong to one office you could embed them therein:

{ office:"...", leads : [ { ... }, { ... } ] }

Likewise the offices could be embedded in an account document.  And so forth.

However whether the above makes sense depends on the operations you plan to do (if fully embedded a query such as "give me all leads" if more work).  Also there is a maximum document size of 16MB.

Likely some combination of embedding and linking is appropriate.  When linking you have to do it client side as you mentioned.  See the [schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) and ["reaching into objects"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) pages on mongodb.org.